# Prevent push message in background

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any way in firebase-messaging-sw.js to prevent push message when my website in background (closed or another website window is active)?

I implemented web-push notifications on my site with Google Firebase service.
firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

I tested it and everything works fine, but when my website window isn't in focus (it's in background) or closed and if I get push-notification it will disappear after 20 seconds.

In my https://hdlava.me/j/firebase_subscribe.js file I added

```
requireInteraction: true
```

flag in messaging.onMessage so if I get push mesage when my website is open the message won't disappear until I click on it.

I tried to add this

```
requireInteraction: true
```

in messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler in my https://hdlava.me/firebase-messaging-sw.js, but it's not working. Even:

```
console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload)
```

doesn't work. It looks like whole messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler does not work.

```
// firebase-messaging-sw.js

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    messagingSenderId: '593513494453'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);
});
```

Can someone please help me figure out what is the problem ? Also if I use in firebase-messaging-sw.js

`self.addEventListener("push",function(event)`

```
self.addEventListener("push",function(event) {
  if (!(self.Notification && self.Notification.permission === 'granted')) {
    return;
  }


  var data = {};
  if (event.data) {
    data = event.data.json();
  }

    console.log(data.notification);

  const notificationTitle = data.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: data.notification.body,
    icon: data.notification.icon,
        click_action: data.notification.click_action,
        requireInteraction: true
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);

});
```

instead `messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler` so I have two messges at once. First message disappears and second one doesn't, but second one is not clickable. Is it possible to prevent first message and make second one to be clickable ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the main purposes of using Firebase Cloud Messaging is to receive messages when the app is not active.

There is no way to prevent receiving a message when the app is not active. But you can:

1. Only do something with the message in the app when it is active, i.e. ignore the message when the app is not active.
2. Only **send** the message from the server when the app is active. This requires that the server somehow knows whether the app is active or not, so you will need to communicate this information from the clients to the server.

Comment: I ask because my messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler does not work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973952/web-push-messaging-setbackgroundmessagehandler-issue
i want to prevent 1st message and handle 2d in self.addEventListener("push"

Comment: If you're having problems getting your code to work, the best way to ask for help is by sharing the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The easier you make it for us to reproduce the problem, the more likely it is that someone will try and hopefully find the cause.